# Removing rows with dates conditional to specific IDs

Tags: r, subset, nested-loops

Basically, I have a data frame that contains IDs, Dates, VolumeX, and VolumeY.

I want to split the VolumeX data frame into before and after the max date of VolumeY specific to an ID.

Ex.

df looks like (with many different IDs) :

```
ID  Date            VolX   VolY
1   2018 - 02- 01   5      -
1   2018 - 03- 01   6      -
1   2018 - 08- 01   3      -
1   2018 - 10- 01   1      -
1   2017 - 02- 01   -      1
1   2014 - 10- 01   -      0
1   2014 - 11- 01   -      5
1   2018 - 02- 01   -      0
```

So for the max date of VolY for every ID, I'd like to split the data frame into two: before and after that date for each ID soas to sum VolX before and after VolY max date.

Seems like this needs to be some kind of nested for loop. I am able to extract max dates and total volume... just having a hard time selecting out ID-specific

Comment: Hi, yould you please show the code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  replace(., . == "-", NA) %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(gsub("\\s", "", Date))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(VolX, VolY), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(ID, Before_After = cumsum(c(0, lag(+(Date == max(Date)))[-1]))) %>%
  mutate(
    sum_Volx = sum(VolX[Date != max(Date)], na.rm = T),
    sum_VolY = sum(VolY[Date != max(Date)], na.rm = T)
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-Before_After)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
     ID Date        VolX  VolY sum_Volx sum_VolY
  <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 2018-02-01     5    NA       14        0
2     1 2018-03-01     6    NA       14        0
3     1 2018-08-01     3    NA       14        0
4     1 2018-10-01     1    NA       14        0
5     1 2017-02-01    NA     1        0        6
6     1 2014-10-01    NA     0        0        6
7     1 2014-11-01    NA     5        0        6
8     1 2018-02-01    NA     0        0        6
```

You could also make separate columns for before/after, like this:

```
df %>%
  replace(., . == "-", NA) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(VolX, VolY), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(gsub("\\s", "", Date)),
    Before_After = cumsum(c(0, lag(+(Date == max(Date)))[-1])),
    sum_Volx_Before = sum(VolX[Date != max(Date) & Before_After == 0], na.rm = T),
    sum_VolY_Before = sum(VolY[Date != max(Date) & Before_After == 0], na.rm = T),
    sum_Volx_After = sum(VolX[Date != max(Date) & Before_After == 1], na.rm = T),
    sum_VolY_After = sum(VolY[Date != max(Date) & Before_After == 1], na.rm = T)
  ) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-Before_After)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 8
     ID Date        VolX  VolY sum_Volx_Before sum_VolY_Before sum_Volx_After sum_VolY_After
  <int> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1 2018-02-01     5    NA              14               0              0              6
2     1 2018-03-01     6    NA              14               0              0              6
3     1 2018-08-01     3    NA              14               0              0              6
4     1 2018-10-01     1    NA              14               0              0              6
5     1 2017-02-01    NA     1              14               0              0              6
6     1 2014-10-01    NA     0              14               0              0              6
7     1 2014-11-01    NA     5              14               0              0              6
8     1 2018-02-01    NA     0              14               0              0              6
```

On the other hand, you could just create 2 separate new data frames in your environment, named `Before` and `After`, that literally exclude the maximum date and summarise the information, like below:

```
df_list <- df %>%
  replace(., . == "-", NA) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(VolX, VolY), as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    Date = as.Date(gsub("\\s", "", Date)),
    Before_After = cumsum(c(0, lag(+(Date == max(Date)))[-1]))
  ) %>%
  filter(!Date == max(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID, Before_After) %>%
  summarise(
    sum_VolX = sum(VolX, na.rm = T),
    sum_VolY = sum(VolY, na.rm = T)
  ) %>%
  split(., .$Before_After)

names(df_list) <- c("Before", "After")
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Let's go through one-by-one:

- first we `replace` the `-` signs by `NA` (not strictly needed, just to avoid errors later on);
- afterwards we transform `VolX` and `VolY` into numeric;
- then we group by `ID` so that everything is applied to each group separately;
- afterwards we transform the `Date` into a proper `Date` format;
- then it is the crucial part: we calculate the flag `Before_After` column where first we flag with `1` if in the previous row the maximum date was observed; afterwards we calculate a cumulative sum of such column, so that everything before this event is 0 and everything after 1;
- then we filter out the maximum `Date`;
- we group again by `ID` and `Before_After` indicator;
- we shrink the data frame with `summarise` so that it only contains the sum of the respective columns;
- we turn the data frame into 2 different ones by splitting on `Before_After` column;
- as the obtained result is a list of 2 data frames, we need to get them into global environment, so first we assign the names to each one and then we turn them into 'proper' data frames.

Output:

```
Before

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Before_After sum_VolX sum_VolY
  <int>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1            0       14        0

After

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   ID [1]
     ID Before_After sum_VolX sum_VolY
  <int>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1            1        0        6
```

Note that 0 corresponds to `Before` and 1 to `After`.

Comment: I think this works - getting error "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" from charToDate(x)... for my df, class(df$Date) is "Date" so I am not sure what this is all about?

Comment: ALSO this may be asking a lot, and I have been meaning to look in to the tidyverse functions more (they're obviously very useful! Could you walk me through the functions you used, briefly?

Comment: I've seen only now that your `Date` column is in a strange format - I've tried to correct this with `gsub`, perhaps now you can re-run and check. Otherwise the solution would be to just remove the part from the code where it says `Date = gsub ...`, since your column is already in a `Date` class as you say. I've also added some explanations to the last code, hope it's helpful!

Comment: Also note that `replace` for the `-` sign is not strictly needed, but I've included it so that errors are not popping up when transforming to `numeric` later on

Comment: That's perfect - thank you so much! Really appreciate the thorough explanation!